# How to know if all your script build in 3.8 works in 3.4 python

Tags: python, python-3.x, py2exe

**Short Question:**
Is there a way to know the script works the same in `3.4`,written in `3.8`?

**Long Question:**
I wrote a script there uses a lot of `if and else`, when I build it in python 3.8.2, I have test each line myself. But now I need to use py2exe (which only supports till `3.4`). So now I want to uninstall my python and install `3.4` but I'm not sure if all my codes will support in it. I started using python from version `3.8` only so I don't know what are the changes that took place from 3.4 to 3.8.2

these are my imports used

```
import pandas as pd
import eel
import bottle_websocket
import tkinter.filedialog
import xlrd
from configparser import ConfigParser
import os
import time
import xlsxwriter
import json
```

As I have used too much of if statements, I dont know `if` some lines inside a `if` will be executed or not.

Comment: Which operating system. You likely can install python 3.4 along side python 3.8. Setup a virtual environment and then you have what you need.

Comment: Don't uninstall anything; maintain a separate 3.4 installation. Virtualenvs are helpful here. The easiest and best way to make sure that all your code works in 3.4 is to *run it in 3.4 and see if it does what it's supposed to*.

Comment: You cannot automatically detect that. Read the [release notes](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/changelog.html) or consider using `cx_Freeze` which supports Python 3.8.

Comment: @Selcuk I heard about cx_freeze but I am not sure if building a ```.exe``` in it will work on  windows 7, 8 and 10. Will it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain 2 different environments in the system.

So try running the code in both the environments and see if you get any warnings or errors.

Generally not much will change for the imports you have shared.